# Xamarin children not being added

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this annoying problem and I don't know how to solve this.

In Xamarin Forms, I'm trying to draw a dynamic layout, for this I load a list of elements (this works). Now i'm trying to display the label for it, so I loop through all the items and add a label for every item. The problem is that the page stays empty.

Yes I initialized the _layout variable as a StackLayout and I also made a ScrollView, then I set the scrollview's content to the _layout variable. But still my page stays empty. I can't share the actual code but I rewrote it using different names.

```
    private void DrawItems()
    {
        var items = (List<Item>)_database.GetItems();
        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            DrawItem(item);
        }
    }

    private void DrawItem(Item item)
    {
        AddLabel(item);
    }

    private void AddLabel(Item item)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Text)) return;
        var label = new Label
        {
            Text = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Number)) ? string.Format("{0}: {1}", item.Number, item.Text) : item.Text,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label))
        };

        _layout.Children.Add(label);
    }
```

For some weird reason, when I start debugging (put a break on var label ...) the label get's created but when I put a break on _layout.Children.Add(label), this never gets called.

Comment: If your breakpoint is not hitted, then it is usually a sign for old bin that weren't deleted in the clean process. Make sure that when you clean your artifacts all the bin is deleted and then try again

Answer (score 0):

When changing UI elements, you need to do it on the main thread.

Try this:

```cs
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    _layout.Children.Add(label);
}
```

---

I've tried the following code, and it works for me. I'm using Xamarin.Forms 1.4.0.6341

```cs
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    StackLayout stack;

    public MyPage()
    {
        var scroll = new ScrollView();
        stack = new StackLayout();

        var btn = new Button {Text = "Add Label"};
        btn.Clicked += (sender, args) => stack.Children.Add(new Label {Text = "Test"});
        stack.Children.Add(btn);

        AddLabelEverySecond();

        scroll.Content = stack;
        Content = scroll;
    }

    private async void AddLabelEverySecond()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            stack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "1 second" });
        }
    }
}
```

Is this applicable to your code? Maybe you could tell us where `DrawItems` is called from?

Comment: Tried this, still no change

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe there's something you can use